# Why does the Foursquare API JS not work with HTTPS?

Tags: foursquare

In a system I have to maintain (didn't build it, just inherited it) we have a Foursquare implementation that hasn't been used in quite a while. Trying to revive it failed, because our page is now loaded via *HTTPS*, which it didn't used to be.

We are using the "Save to Foursquare" button as well as the API request to retrieve the number of Check-ins. I already switched all the JS includes and intent links from http to https and at least now it shows the number and the button correctly.

However, I can't *click* the button and checking the browser's console I found that it added a script tag to the head of this page which tries to access `http://platform.foursquare.com/js/modules/widgets.asyncbundle.js`. The browser obviously blocks this, because it's not using HTTPS.

The file we are explicitly loading is `https://platform.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js`. It seems to me like this script is not reacting correctly to HTTP vs. HTTPS. There is probably a very simple solution to this, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've tried it yet but the foursquare website says this on the matter:

1. Change the source of the JavaScript file to https://platform-s.foursquare.com/js/widgets.js
2. Add {"secure":true} to the global configuration block (window.___fourSq)`

The same link (see below) has all the different ways to call the `Save To Foursquare` function using its `.saveTo()` function.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/widgets

I hope this information and links helps! Cheers.

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I missed that. Almost feels like I was looking at a completely different documentation. Sadly, I have no way of actually testing your suggestion right now, but it sure looks like exactly what I was looking for. Will try to verify it soon. Thanks!